# When is a three-manifold deck transformation group solvable?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fundamental-group, 3-manifolds, solvable-groups

Suppose that $\pi:Y \to Y'$ is a regular covering of closed, connected, orientable three-manifolds and let $G$ be the deck transformation group.  Furthermore, suppose that $Y$ is a rational homology sphere (I don't know how much this condition matters).  It's not always the case that $G$ is solvable, since one can take $Y$ to be $S^3$ and $Y'$ to be the Poincare homology sphere.  Are there other examples where $G$ is not solvable?  Are such examples classified?  If $Y$ has elliptic geometry, this is the only example (I think), but I have no clue in general.  This seems like it could be related to residual finiteness of three-manifold groups/RFRS/LERF/other four-letter acronyms I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cooper and Long showed [you can realize any finite group acting on a rational
homology sphere](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641%2898%2900116-3).

There's no general sort of classification that I know of. Maybe what you're asking for is,
given $Y'$ a rational homology sphere, and a homomorphism $\varphi: \pi_1(Y')\to K$, where $K$ is a finite group,
when is the cover $Y\to Y'$ corresponding to $ker(\varphi)$ again a rational
homology sphere? One perspective is that this amounts to computing $H_1(Y; \mathbb{Z}[K])$,
homology with twisted coefficients. [Dunfield and Thurston](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1988291) took advantage of this
to compute covers of manifolds in the Snappea census with positive first betti number,
but such computations can get rapidly complicated, so I don't know of any general pattern when $K$ is non-solvable.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for free actions of finite, nonsolvable groups on $Y$. If you truly don't care that $Y$ is a rational homology sphere, for any finite group $G$ there exists a closed, connected, orientable 2-manifold $X$ and a free action of $G$ on $X$, so $G$ also acts freely on $Y = X \times S^1$.

Comment: Yes, that is a good observation.  I really want to restrict to rational homology spheres then.  

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but a classification of solvable groups which are fundamental groups of compact 3-manifolds is given the following celebrated paper:

Thomas, C. B.
On 3-manifolds with finite solvable fundamental group. 
Invent. Math. 52 (1979), no. 2, 187–197.

It is very easy to check which of the manifolds produced are rational homology spheres...